# Content Type Segmentation

Tags: nodes, entities

I need to know if there is a way to create a content type and within the content type to create a field which this field should be segment.

For Example :

at the beginning i will have an image,  this will be the default image.
and in case i will choose an option like to display only for authenticated user another image field will be opened , and in the display all unauthenticated users will see the default image and authenticated users will see the second image.

Is there something like this ?

Thanks

Comment: are you using 7 or 8?

Comment: I am using on 7 But i will be glad to hear also about 8

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template for that specific content type like

```
node--yourcontenttype.tpl.php
```

and inside you can check for the user roles like so

```
// Load the currently logged in user.
global $user;

// Check if the user has the 'editor' role.
if (in_array('editor', $user->roles)) {
  // print one image
} else {
  //print the other one
}
```

Comment: But in this situtation if i have multi segmentation the ui will be very long. Also in case i am pulling this data in a view i need to create a nother template for that view